# Map legend is not working in GWC WMS and WMTS

Tags: geoserver, wms, legend, geowebcache, wmts

I am not getting map legend in GWC WMTS or WMS service, QGIS returns an error "Returned legend image is flawed". but when I am accessing that layer using WMS in QGIS, Map legend is showing with the layer.[image][image] Also, When I am accessing a small area with the same style, Map legend is showing in GWC WMS service. [image]
I am using GeoServer version 2.12.2. 
GWC WMS link: http://localhost/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?
WMS link:  http://localhost/geoserver/wms?

Anyone knows why Map legend is not working in GWC WMS and WMTS?

Comment: Can you capture the request that is sent by QGIS to the GeoServer GWC when it gets the error?  (For example use Fiddler and in QGIS use the  Settings > Options > Network dialogue to configure an httpProxy).

Comment: I have captured the request in Fiddler. For request GetLegendGraphics, it returns "This response is encoded, but does not claim to be an image". and request header is "GET /localhost/gwc/service/wms?SERVICE=WMS&&VERSION=1.1.1&SLD_VERSION=1.1.0&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&FORMAT=image/jpeg&LAYER=DTM&STYLE=&TRANSPARENT=true HTTP/1.1"

Comment: does WMTS supports Map legend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this problem. Previously at the time of publishing the layer, I had selected Tile Image Formats: JPEG. Whereas Map legend supports only PNG format. So NOW, I have selected Tile Image Formats to PNG and I am getting map legend in GWC WMS.